# Is it possible to use a value in d[x] register as address in vld?

Tags: c++, arm, simd, neon

I have an Image with sizes M x N, and each pixel is 14 bits (all of them are stored in 16 bit integers but  2 least significant bits are not used).  I want to map each pixel to an 8 bit value, due to a mapping function which is simply an array of 16384 values. I perform this image tone mapping using pure C++ as follows:

```
for(int i=0;i<imageSize;i++)
{
    resultImage[i] = mappingArray[image[Index]];
}
```

However, I want to optimize this operation using ARM Neon intrinsics. Since there are 32 (correct it if I'm wrong) neon (dx) registers registers, I cannot use VTBL instruction for a lookup table larger than

**8x32 = 256** elements. Moreover, there is another discussion on stacoverflow to use a lookup table larger than 32 bytes:

[ARM NEON: How to implement a 256bytes Look Up table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22158186/arm-neon-how-to-implement-a-256bytes-look-up-table)

How can I manage to optimize such simple looking operation? I think of using pixels of the image as address parameter of VLD function just as something like the following:

VLD1.8 {d1},[d0] ??

Is it possible? Or how can I handle this?

Comment: I may be mistaken, but the VTBL instruction supports only 4 registers, not 32. In 7 VTBL instructions, you could acces 28 of them, but don't forget that you need another NEON register just to hold your pixel value. That leaves you with just 31 registers for the lookups.

Comment: You seem to have put much effort in solving this performance issue. Could you be more specific on the nature of the said transformation? Like sh1 said, brute force computation might solve the problem more elegantly considering NEON's superior computing power.

Answer (score 2):

The optimization in the other example works by holding an entire lookup table in registers. You simply cannot do this: your table is 16384 bytes (2^14 -> 2^8), and that is way, way more than you have in register space.

Hence, your table will reside in L1 cache. The obvious C++ code:

```
unsigned char mappingArray[16384];
fill(mappingArray);
for(int i=0;i<imageSize;i++)
{
    resultImage[i] = mappingArray[image[i]>>2];
}
```

will probably compile straight to the most efficient code. The problem isn't how you get things in registers. The problem is that you need memory access to your input image, mapping table and output image.

If speed was a problem, I'd solve this by aggressively trimming the table to perhaps 128 entries, and using linear interpolation on the next few bits.

Comment: `image[i] >> 2`, the two _least_ significant bits are not used.

Answer (score 1):

Given a large look-up table, the normal process is to look very closely at it to figure out (or find on the internet) the algorithm to compute each entry.  If that algorithm turns out to be simple enough then you might find that it's faster to perform the calculations in parallel rather than to perform scalar table look-ups.

Alternatively, based on the shape of the data you can try to find approximations which are up to requirements but which are easier to compute.

For example, you can use VTBL on the top three or four bits of the input, and linear interpolation on the rest.  But this only works if the curve is smooth enough that linear interpolation is an adequate approximation.

A common operation which matches the parameters stated is linear to sRGB conversion; in which case you're looking at raising each input to the power of 5/12.  That's a bit hairy, but you might still be able to get some performance gain if you don't need to be too accurate.